# uploadArchives build both debug and release

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an upload task in my gradle script:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/apps-releases")     {
                    authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
                snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/apps-snapshots") {
                    authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.groupId = "$defaultApplicationId"
            pom.artifactId = 'MyApp'
            pom.version = applicationVersionName()
        }
    }
}
```

And running this from teamcity with:

```
clean assembleDebug testDebugUnitTest crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug uploadArchives
```

After building the debug version it seems like *uploadArchives* is building a release version too. So when the build is done I have both a debug and release apk as generated artefacts from the build. But if I remove *uploadArchives* it only generates debug apk.

Is there anyway to prevent this? It's not a big deal but it would be nice to only build the version I'm specifying; i.e. *uploadDebugArchives* and *uploadReleaseArchives* would be nice...

Answer (score 6):

See here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication

Set `defaultPublishConfig` to the buildtype you want to publish.

Comment: Thanks. But as I understand it you would only publish one then, the one you specify. We want to publish both, but when we specify release build or debug build. Not at the same time (i.e. we have snapshots "debug") that we publish much more often than releases.

Comment: *>Not at the same time* Does that not mean you're only publishing one buildtype?

Comment: Yes, at a time yes. Snapshot a lot more often than releases.

Comment: Deprecated. Is there another solution for the same?